# Access to XAMPP htdocs folder

Tags: xampp

I'm facing an issue while trying to open a directory in XAMPP.

The installation was successful, but when accessing a directory in `htdocs`, the server immediately returns to the `XAMPP control panel` without opening the directory.

I've checked the documentation and other similar questions, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you can't see the file you copy to `xampp/htdocs` folder in the browser, you probably didn't browse the right URL in browser:

file in the `/xampp/htdocs/PATH_OR_FILE` folder, could see it in the browser at the `http://localhost/PATH_OR_FILE` address.

**Example:**

`/xampp/htdocs/test.html` --> **`http://localhost/test.html`**

`/xampp/htdocs/folder/test.php` --> **`http://localhost/folder/test.php`**

`/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.html` --> **`http://localhost/folder/index.html`**

`/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.php` --> **`http://localhost/folder/index.php`**

**Browsing a folder:**

the `index.*` if default for XAMPP (you can change it in settings). So:

`/xampp/htdocs/index.html` or `/xampp/htdocs/index.php` --> **`http://localhost`**

`/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.html` or `/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.php` --> **`http://localhost/folder`**